# Switch between Storyboard-Viewcontrollers with code instead of transitions-lines

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I wanted to ask how you can switch between two ViewControllers without using the transitionlines on the storyboard or xib-files.

Let me describe my problem here:
I got a tableview. Within this table view are different entries, but I wanted to do different 
onclick-actions. I can already differ what entry has been clicked and got a switch case to do different actions.

I want only in some cases to change the current view controller. How can I do that?
I would need some construct like this:

switch(...)
    0: stuff
    1: more stuff
    2: some magical stuff
    3: ->> change the view controller
    default

Is this even possible with storyboards?

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: on Did click item atIndexPath you implement this thing. At the switch case you could go to any viewController you want. You can push or present viewControllers programmatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there are two ways you can switch viewcontrollers.  The first is using a segue (which are the lines you were talking about before, though they are more versatile than you think).  The second is to programmatically create the second view and set it as the main view controller.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that you want to perform a segue given a certain condition.

eg:

```
if (some condition is met) {
    change view controllers
} else {
    do nothing
}
```

is this correct?  if so, then what you can do is set up a segue and put it in a conditional.  So, go to your storyboard, hold control and click on the first view controller and drag to the next one (note: do not click on a button, click on the view controller itself).  Next, name your segue by clicking the little circle in the middle of the segue line and go to attributes inspector (the shield looking thing).  Name the segue whatever you want, eg: "toSecondController"

the following code will call the segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecondController" sender:self];
```

so, you can put this in a conditional so you can control when the second controller is called.

```
if (some condition is met) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toExtraHosts" sender:self];
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

edit: just reread your post and the following code will work:

```
switch (...)
    {
        case 0:
            //thing 1
        case 1:
            //thing 2
        case 2:
            //thing 3
        case 3:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toExtraHosts" sender:self];
        default:
            //default thing
    }
```

However, you have to make sure the segue is from the **viewcontrollers**, not from the **buttons**.  The reason is that if you make a segue from a button to another view controller, the segue is called automatically.  If you make it from a viewcontroller to a viewcontroller, it is only called when you call it programmatically with performSegueWithIdentifier

Hope that answers your question